# .NET MVC - How to utilize custom settings provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, application-settings

I have created a custom settings provider to store my application settings in a separate XML file. I've created settings and values through Visual studio (`Solution` -> `My Project` -> `Settings`) and specified my custom provider.

It doesn't seem to be 'used' by the application. I can put breakpoints everywhere in my custom provider, but they are not touched... Am I missing something here? **How do I *use* my custom settings provider?**

1. Create the provider
2. Enter settings + reference to custom provider in VS
3. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CustomSettingsProvider.aspx). It sounds like this is what you're trying to do.

It's for Winforms, and I'm not sure how it translates, but make sure you are actually setting each different setting to *use* the custom provider. In Winforms, this is done as a `Provider` property on each of the settings.

Comment: Lol i'm using that one, however i can't get it to work... The provider somehow isn't being picked up.

Comment: You're using the same tutorial? I've got to warn you not to use exceptions like in the tutorial, though. Better to check for a `null` node on return instead.